# limits for hooked right arrow in the equation not working

Tags: equations

help me to code this equation with limits for hookedrightarrow
limits for hookedright arrow not coming

[image]

Tried codes

```
\underset{\hookedrightarrow}{i}<br/>
```

but not getting correct format.

Comment: Looking at the title of your question I would expect some code (which is not working). So, please show what you have tried so far in form of a self-contained and [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/).

Comment: Useful Tip: On TeXLive distro [`texdoc mathmode`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) at terminal/commandline window section `35
Limits` on page 62 `Mathmode.tex
v.2.47`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\overset` from »[amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)« instead of your approach.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % loads »amsmath«

\begin{document}
  \[
    A \overset{i}{\hookrightarrow} B
  \]
\end{document}
```

---

[image]